# Is the subset compact?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be the set of all bounded real sequences $\vec{x} = \{x_1,
x_2, \ldots \}$ with metric
$d$ defined by
$$d(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = \sup_n |x_n - y_n|.$$
The subset $E$ consisting of all sequences $\vec{x}$ such that
$d(\vec{x},\vec{0}) \leq 1$ is plainly a
closed subset of $X$. Is $E$ compact?

Attempt: We note that $E$  is bounded because $d(\vec{x},\vec{0}) \leq 1$. So E is closed and bounded . By Heine-Borel, E is compact. Is this ok?

Comment: Are you sure that the Heine-Borel Theorem applies to this metric space?

Comment: Consider using one of these characterizations of compactness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Metric_spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Consider the sequence $\vec{x}_n$ where all the terms are zero with the exception of the $n$th-term which is equal to $1$. Does the sequence of sequences $(\vec{x}_n)_n$, which is contained in $E$, admit a convergent subsequence?

Comment: No. Because of the nth-term =1??

Comment: But by Bolzano Weirstrass every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. I am getting confused.

Comment: This is a sequence of sequences... Bolzano Weirstrass holds in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here we are dealing with an infinite dimensional space.

Comment: Oh! So we since we have a sequence of sequences that does not converge, we do not have compactness. Right?

Comment: @Dom Yes, exactly.